# Getting blank response from Google Talent API

Tags: php, google-api, artificial-intelligence, google-api-php-client

I am targeting to load Google Jobs search result in my custom website.
So for that I created account on google and enable [Google Talent API](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/talent-solution/). After enable billing on google cloud API account, they allow me request to this API using API Key and Service account credentials.

I am currently using PHP with the use of api-client-php library.

For that I have download .json file for credential (client_secret.json) from google Console Talent Platform.

Here is my sample code in PHP.

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

// Instantiate the client
$client = new Google_Client();

$api_key = 'AdsadsIzaSyBYAMxEPPasdadadw5VHITCdREQW7WYeIGs8jRlUYqlzLM';
$client->setDeveloperKey($api_key);
$client->setAuthConfig(getcwd() . '/client_secret.json');
$client->setScopes(array(
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/jobs',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'
));
$jobs = new Google_Service_JobService($client);
$location='USA';

// Set the Metadata
$requestMetadata = new Google_Service_JobService_RequestMetadata();
$requestMetadata->setUserId('000aaaa');
$requestMetadata->setSessionId('000aaaa-1212-21212');
$requestMetadata->setDomain('www.google.com');
$jobQuery = new Google_Service_JobService_JobQuery();
$keyword='software OR java';
$jobQuery->setQuery($keyword);

// Search Job Request
$searchRequest = new Google_Service_JobService_SearchJobsRequest();
$searchRequest->setRequestMetadata($requestMetadata);
$searchRequest->setQuery($jobQuery);
$searchRequest->setMode('JOB_SEARCH');
$jobService = new Google_Service_JobService($client);

$response = $jobService->jobs->search($searchRequest);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($response);
print_r($response->matchingJobs);
```

While sending this request, We are getting matchingjobs  blank array but $response have some object array. which is something like not output but just request information.

here is the response which we are getting so far using Talent Search API.

```
Google_Service_JobService_SearchJobsResponse Object
(
    [collection_key:protected] => matchingJobs
    [appliedCommuteFilterType:protected] => Google_Service_JobService_CommutePreference
    [appliedCommuteFilterDataType:protected] => 
    [appliedJobLocationFiltersType:protected] => Google_Service_JobService_JobLocation
    [appliedJobLocationFiltersDataType:protected] => array
    [estimatedTotalSize] => 
    [histogramResultsType:protected] => Google_Service_JobService_HistogramResults
    [histogramResultsDataType:protected] => 
    [jobView] => 
    [matchingJobsType:protected] => Google_Service_JobService_MatchingJob
    [matchingJobsDataType:protected] => array
    [metadataType:protected] => Google_Service_JobService_ResponseMetadata
    [metadataDataType:protected] => 
    [nextPageToken] => 
    [numJobsFromBroadenedQuery] => 0
    [spellResultType:protected] => Google_Service_JobService_SpellingCorrection
    [spellResultDataType:protected] => 
    [totalSize] => 
    [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [modelData:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [processed:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [metadata] => Google_Service_JobService_ResponseMetadata Object
        (
            [collection_key:protected] => experimentIdList
            [experimentIdList] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 11300310
                    [1] => 11300342
                )

            [mode] => JOB_SEARCH
            [requestId] => f5cacd36-db29-4d65-851f-34a97c98af79:APAb7IRQAVop4QZ6rC2OlKjcEARRJQHI8w==
            [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [modelData:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [processed:protected] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
Array
(
)
```

I am confuse here, Talent API can search and load google Jobs on our website **OR** we need to create company and jobs and they just provide Advanced search filter using AI and ML ?

Lets if they provide google Jobs on our website then what is wrong in my code ?

Please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

Google's Talent API only works with data you provide it, so yes, you should create companies and jobs and then apply the searches to those jobs.

The second step in the [checklist](https://cloud.google.com/talent-solution/job-search/docs/launch) they've published for launching apps that use this API is **Index companies and jobs**, with clear mentions of these being from your own database:

> Create at least one Company. We recommend creating Company objects for
> all companies in your database with open jobs.
>
> Create Jobs for your Companies. We recommend creating Job objects for
> all open jobs in your database.

Additional proof that supports this disappointing reality is an [article](https://medium.com/@idavchev/google-job-search-api-559f81141dae) published by Ivan Davchev after the Google conference where this API was announced:

> **What Is Google Jobs API?**
>
> It is a turn-key solution to searching *your* jobs. Like most cloud-based search > solutions, you need to feed it documents (jobs) which it indexes and makes searchable.
>
> [...]
>
> It is **not an aggregator** and does not offer “all jobs in the world” out of the box. > So you can’t build an Indeed competitor in an afternoon with this API. It only searches > what you provide it, which is why it makes sense for job boards and applicant tracking > systems (ATS) to use it — jobs are posted on and managed by those systems.

Comment: > It is not an aggregator and does not offer “all jobs in the world” out of the box.

Now they have Google Jobs that seems to be an aggregator.